# C# - Kill a threaded process from a button_click

Tags: c#

I'm trying to kill notepad.exe using a button click event.

It need to be in a thread because of the process.WaitForExit();

Right now, the button click does nothing at all, can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Here is my current code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace WpfApp5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Thread mythread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad.exe";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        });

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mythread.Start();   
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mythread.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you suppose it to do?

Comment: It looks like you're closing the thread, which is the problem you mentioned. Looks like you instead want to close the process running along with it, too, for visual feedback. You'd need to, in your Button_Click_1 function, find the process and then kill it.

Not a very thread safe method to be calling, Process. Certainly seems like an [X, Y problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys :) //
Tu Tran: I'm trying to kill notepad.exe in this exemple // 
James Whyte: I've looked for this options but the exe that I run  (Which is not Notepad.exe, lol) seems to dislike being killed by process name, it throws a bunch of errors.

Comment: Thread#Abort() just stops the thread, means the code is not run anymore, it does not revert what the code did. Therefore, in order to kill the process, you should keep process id when it started, then kill the process based on that id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimum change in your code, you can do it like below,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static Process process; //making process class level member;
    Thread mythread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad.exe";
        process.Start();
    });

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mythread.Start();   
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        process.Kill(); //killing the actual process.
        mythread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution but it throw me this error on the three "process": "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property"

Comment: @JonnyLeo yes, I forgot that to add, See my edit now. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, that does it !

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need the thread. You're already starting a separate process, which has its own set of threads.
2. All you need to do is hang onto `process` (e.g. as a member variable) and kill it.

For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Process _process = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _process = new Process();
        _process.StartInfo.FileName = @"notepad.exe";
        _process.Start();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_process == null) return;
        _process.Kill();
        _process = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The process has to be in a thread, didn't mention it first but I have to use process.WaitForExit(); and that would make the UI not to load. Thanks for the answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your application (and thread) runs in its own process separate from the one you started. Killing the thread in your process won't kill the other process. You need to look at [System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx)